# Why does WebApi fail to bind a System.Version parameter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

**UPDATE**: solved! Nothing to see here, please move on :-)

I have an `ApiController` method that takes a `System.Version` parameter. The parameter is passed in the request body, as JSON. This is what gets sent:

{
  "Major": 0,
  "Minor": 7,
  "Build": 0,
  "Revision": 0,
  "MajorRevision": 0,
  "MinorRevision": 0
}

The routing works - my method is being called - but the parameter has an empty `Version` object (all values zero). Why?

Here's the declaration of the controller method:

```
    // POST api/service/details
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Details")]
    public ServiceDto Get(Version version)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Ah, this'll be why... it's not serializable: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2085866/98422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent anyone else from trying to answer this, the answer is that the System.Version class has no public setters on its members. Hence it cannot be de-serialized properly, and remains in its initial state. I had to use my own "Version" class that had publicly-settable members, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think [Serializable] could be an issue.

Try putting 'Content-Type: application/json' as header from the client side.
Also use [FromBody] attribute like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Details")]
public ServiceDto Get([FromBody]Version version)
{
}
```

Comment: I already had both of those things. I really don't think there's any doubt that the behaviour I got was simply due to the fact that the Version class has no public setters on its members. Hence it cannot be de-serialized properly, and remains in its initial state. When I switched from using System.Version to my own replica of the Version class, it worked fine.