# POST request throwing null exception

Tags: c#, linq, post, asp.net-web-api

I am writing to seek help, in regards creating a POST request from private method.  I currently have two methods GET and POST, which gets input parameters from private method.  When I call the POST method using Fiddler:

Fiddler - Testing POST Request:
In the composer tab of the Fiddler, I copy in the URL -- `[http://localhost:45361/api/test]`. In the Request header box:

```
 User-Agent: Fiddler
 Content-Type: application/json;
 Host: localhost:45361
 Content-Length: 16
 Authorization: Basic ###########==
```

In the Request Body box:

```
 {"name":"prets"}
```

From the following above input, I get a **NullReferenceException** on the following line of code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
```

However, if I call the GET method from the same private method, I am able to get  okay response of 200, **but not for POST request**

I have tried adding a verification for the query object, but the POST request still shows the output as 404 error, i.e. "something went wrong with the query".

```
     public  HttpContext Current { get; set; }

     [HttpGet]
     public HttpResponseMessage get([FromUri] Query query)
     {
         return method(Current, query);
     }
     [HttpPost]
     public HttpResponseMessage post([FromBody] Query query)
     {
         return method(Current, query);
     }

     private HttpResponseMessage method(HttpContext request, Query query)
     {
     if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
         {
             IQueryable<data> Data = null;

             //verifying the query
             if (query != null)
             {

             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
             {
                 var ids = query.name.Split(',');

                 var dataMatchingTags = db.database_data.Where(c => ids.Any(id => c.Name.Contains(id)));

                 if (Data == null)
                     Data = dataMatchingTags;
                 else
                     Data = Data.Union(dataMatchingTags);
             }

                 if (Data == null)
                     Data = db.data;

                 if (query.endDate != null)
                 {
                     Data = Data.Where(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate);
                 }
                 Data = Data.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate);
                 var data = Data.ToList();

                 if (!data.Any())
                 {
                     var message = string.Format("No data");
                     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
                 }
                 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
             }

             return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "something wrong with query statement.");
         }
             return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Access Denied");
         }
```

here is my object model class - Query:

```
 public class Query
  {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> startDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> endDate{ get; set; }
  }
```

I am calling the POST request from my controller only, as I have not embedded POST request from the client-end.  I am using Fiddler, to test out the POST calls.

I am slightly struggling, in what other approach I can take, to get this resolved.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting `NullReferenceException ` on `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))`? What is the full exception message? Have you tried to manually debug the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with earlier commenter, the nullpointer can't come from the line you say...
One null-pointer waiting to happen though is:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
{
    //do something
}
if (Data == null)
{
    Data = db.data; //this will always be null if the query object was null
}
```

This is assuming that you create/populate the 'db' object in the commented out block.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my original code.

Comment: I was originally getting a `NullReferenceException` error on the  query.name, but when I added in the following line of code  `if (query != null)`, I am now experiencing 404 error, and in the output response, it shows "something wrong with query statement". Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that you are POSTing and not GETing? Since you say you call the method with a url where you have the name as a query-param. For POST to work you'd need to include it as an input-value in a html-form.

Comment: Apology for the late response and not making my question coherent, I have updated the question above, showing how I am passing the input parameters for the POST request in fiddler.  My current issue, is that I keep experiencing the `query null` in fiddler, when calling POST request and I would like to seek some guidance, into how can I resolve this issue, please.  Many thanks for your reply and help.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on WebAPI and fiddler, but if I were you, I'd try it with a form you create yourself in a simple html file. It looks to me that the problem lies in that you don't get the values correctly submitted to the server. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the post-method and checking what the Query obbject contains there?

Comment: and also, check this question if you're having the same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016563/webapi-controller-gives-nulls?rq=1

Comment: Hi again, Thank you for your suggestion on the issue.  I keep getting `query as null`, when I debugged the POST method and the Private Method. Sadly, the link did not help to resolve the issue but thank you anyways.  Could the issue be the type of request `HttpContext request`, I am using which is preventing the information to be submitted to the server. I tried playing around with the WebAPI routing but not sure, if that is suitable approach.  I appreciate your time and hardwork. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried POSTing from a html-page you've created yourself, containing only a form with the name parameter? I just fired up a blank webapi project and tried with a simple html-form, which worked fine!

Comment: Dear @aeliusd, thank you very much for your help and suggestion.  I tried creating html-page and I was able to run the POST request successfully, as the real issue was in the Fiddler settings.  In the end, I got it to work.  Thank you so much for time and support.