# Obscure behavior with XmlMessageFormatter serializing System.Version

Tags: xml-serialization

I am using MSMQ together with the XmlMessageFormatter serializer.

mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(TransportEnvelop), typeof(System.Version) } );
msg = new TransportEnvelop(new Version(0, 1, 0, 1), DateTime.Now);
mq.Send(msg);

I am writing out the generated message to the console and the set version
is right there.

If I read back the message from the queue, the System.Verion values is
"0.0" [through Console.WriteLine].

If I look into the queue with the admin tool, I see:

```
<Version/>
```

If I replace the System.Version class with my own Version class,
everything is like I expect.

Has someone probably an idea, what I am doing wrong???

Thanks anyway and
best regards,

++mabra

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate:
[System.Version not serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085866/system-version-not-serialized)

I'm running into a similar problem sending Version as an attribute of a WCF call ,but it's not working now and it used to be fine. I think it's related to an upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012. However, it works just fine locally, but not on the server. So that makes me theorize that it can be influenced by a system configuration or how IIS is set up. I'm not 100% sure where that might be though.