# XML version data to System.Version

Tags: c#, xml

I normally use JSON only, so I apologize if this is a low found question. I am pulling in xml data from a web page and embedded within is a version of SW that I need to know if I should update. In JSON I simply change the type of the field to Version and it changes the string to a Version that can be handled, I have not found a similar method in xml constructor.

The code being used was VS2015 generated from a paste of the data as a generic value.

```
 [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = true)]
    public partial class xml
    {

        private xmlSoftware softwareField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public xmlSoftware software
        {
            get
            {
                return this.softwareField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.softwareField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = false)]
public partial class xmlSoftware
{

    private xmlSoftwareCheckforupdates checkforupdatesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public xmlSoftwareCheckforupdates checkforupdates
    {
        get
        {
            return this.checkforupdatesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.checkforupdatesField = value;
        }
    }
}
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = false)]
    public partial class xmlSoftwareCheckforupdates
    {

        private string latest_versionField;

        //Other Stuff before and after this item
        /// <remarks/>
        public string latest_version
        {
            get
            {
                return this.latest_versionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.latest_versionField = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you can either a) deserialize the XML response into an object via the generated serializer code or b) parse the raw XML to get the value.  Since you already have the code to serialize/deserialize, probably best to deserialize the XML into an object and check the value in the `latest_version` property of `xmlSoftwareCheckforupdates`.

Comment: @Tim attempted this by having it set as object, then using 'value as Version`. I wanted it to change to Version on deserialize instead of having to convert to Version on first use.

Comment: so you want the property name to be "Version"?  Add `[XmlElementAttribute(Name = "Version")] above `public xmlSoftwareCheckforupdates`.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking so can you post some sample code of what you've tried?

Comment: If you are looking to serialize `System.Version` with `XmlSerializer` see [this answer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962224/3744182) to [System.Version not serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2085866/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Thanks, that worked well for me. I figured it had to be a duplicate, my search skills have seemed to failed me once again.